# Como ler duas variáveis inteiras na mesma linha?

Tags: python

Como  ler duas variáveis inteiras na mesma linha com Python?

```
a= int(input())

b = int(input())
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/como-atribuir-3-valores-para-3-vari%c3%a1veis-em-apenas-uma-linha-de-entrada-em-pytho/461242#461242).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código abaixo deve ajudar:

```
N, M = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
```

Comment: Não gostairia de explicar um pouco oq ue acotnece nessa linha/ Ela está correta, ma spode ser mágicca demias para quem perguntou ou oturas pessoas coma  mesma dúvida.

Comment: A questão é :  **"Como o código abaixo vai ajudar?"**. Você precisa explicar.  Parece estar respondendo para alguém que vai entender. Porém, outros usuários gostariam de se beneficiar dessa resposta.