# Como atribuir 3 valores para 3 variáveis em apenas uma linha de entrada em python?

Tags: python

```
# Esse é um programa que você irá digitar 3 pontuações e ele irá te informar o vice campeão (ou segundo lugar)  


# Existe algum método de atribuir o valor de a, b e c em apenas uma linha na entrada?  
# Eu escrevo na entrada por exemplo: 10 11 9
# E o programa atribuirá 10 a variável a, 11 a b, e 9 a c 
# Como faço isso?

# No caso, queria substituir os próximos 3 comentários

#a= int (input ("Digite a pontuação: "))
#b= int (input ("Digite a pontuação: "))
#c= int (input ("Digite a pontuação: "))

print()

if (a < b) and (a > c):
    print ("O vice campeão é: " , a)

elif (a > b) and (a < c):
  print ("O vice campeão é: " , a)

if (b < a) and (b > c):
    print ("O vice campeão é: " , b)

elif (b > a) and (b < c):
    print ("O vice campeão é: " , b)   

if (c < b) and (c > a):
    print ("O vice campeão é: " , c)

elif (c > b) and (c < a):
    print ("O vice campeão é: " , c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um primeiro passo seria pegar as pontuações e chamar o método `split` pra obter uma lista em que cada elemento é uma das pontuações:

```
pontuacoes = input("Digite as pontuações: ").split()
```

Em seguida, temos que transformar essas pontuações que no momento são strings em inteiros. Podemos fazer isso com uma compreensão de lista:

```
pontuacoes_int = [int(p) for p in pontuacoes]
```

Agora, `pontuacoes_int` é uma lista com as pontuações como valores inteiros. Se quisermos atribuir esses valores a variáveis separadas, podemos fazer

```
a, b, c = pontuacoes_int
```

Outro jeito de fazer isso sem compreensão de lista poderia ser assim:

```
pontuacoes = input("Digite as pontuações: ").split()
a, b, c = int(pontuacoes[0]), int(pontuacoes[1]), int(pontuacoes[2])
```

Esse método também funciona, mas é interessante aprender a usar compreensões de lista (ou `map`) porque daí o seu código funciona independentemente do número de elementos que precisam ser transformados em inteiros.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, mas ainda tenho outra duvida: tem como utilizar esse mesmo método  com listas verticais?

Comment: @GustavoMatias como assim listas verticais?

Comment: É dificil explicar aqui mas ao invés de digitar " 10 9 8 " um do lado do outro, por exemplo, se eu digitasse estes números um embaixo do outro? O programa ( modificado do jeito que você disse ) funcionaria do mesmo jeito?

Comment: @GustavoMatias proponho que publiques outra questão, pois esta dúvida pelos está esclarecida e deves aceitar a resposta como tal. A nova dúvida não tem relação com esta

Answer (score 4):

No Python a atribuição de valores a variáveis é muito legal.

Veja um exemplo:

```
idade, nome, cidade = 21, 'Paulo', 'São Paulo'
```

No exemplo acima, em uma única linha atribuímos 3 valores a 3 variáveis.
Basta separar os valores e as variáveis utilizando uma vírgula.

Outros exemplos simples:

```
nome, idade, cidade = input('Digite seu Nome: '), int(input('Digite sua idade: ')), input('Digite sua Cidade: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Diversas são as formas que temos no **Python** para **capturar vários valores** a partir de **um só input()**.

Pois bem, para capturar **todos os 3 valores** para usar no seu código podemos utilizar a seguinte linha de comandos:

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input('Digite os valores de "A", "B" e "C": ').split()]
```

Observe que quando utilizamos esta linha de comandos, os valores digitados são armazenados em uma lista, na qual a variável `a` receberá o primeiro índice da lista, a variável `b` receberá o segundo índice da lista e a variável `c` receberá o terceiro índice da lista.

Com esta linha de comandos o seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input('Digite os valores de "A", "B" e "C": ').split()]

if (a < b) and (a > c):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", a)

elif (a > b) and (a < c):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", a)

if (b < a) and (b > c):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", b)

elif (b > a) and (b < c):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", b)

if (c < b) and (c > a):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", c)

elif (c > b) and (c < a):
    print("O vice campeão é: ", c)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores de "A", "B" e "C":` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos os valores de A, B e C**, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, o código realizará as operações de comparações e nos exibirá o resultado.

Agora, se você também tiver interesse em reduzir bastante a quantidade de linhas deste código, poderás utilizar o seguinte código:

```
valores = sorted([int(x) for x in input('Valores os valores de "A", "B" e "C": ').split()], reverse=True)
maior = max(valores)

for c in valores:
    if c < maior:
        print(f'O vice campeão tem: {c} pontos')
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos este segundo código recebemos a mesma mensagem do código anterior. Neste momento devemos digitar os valores tal como digitamos no código anterior e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida o código armazenará todos os valores digitados no input dentro da lista `valores` ordenados de forma `decrescente`. Posteriormente, o código calculará o `maior` valor da lista `valores`. Em seguida o bloco `for` percorrerá os elementos da lista `valores` e com a ajuda do bloco `if` será verificado se o valor armazenado temporariamente na variável `c` é **menor** que a variável `maior`. Caso a verificação seja **negativa**, o `for` encerrará a referida iteração e executará a próxima. Caso a verificação seja **positiva**, o `print()` exibirá a pontuação do **vice campeão** e, com a ajuda do `break`, encerrará a execução do bloco `for`, produzindo desta forma, o encerramento geral do código.

**Observação:**

Outra forma de capturar vários valores a partir de **um só input** é:

```
valores = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: [Veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427259/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-incluir-mais-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-por-input-no-python/464028#464028)