# É possível incluir mais de uma variável por 'input' no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Em C eu posso fazer isso:

```c
printf("Informe 3 numeros');
scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);
```

Posso fazer um processo similar em Python? Fiz umas buscas e encontrei que posso fazer assim:

```py
a,b,c = input('informe 3 numeros: ').split("")
print(a,'',b,'',c)
```

Mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/Administrador/Google Drive/Exercicios Python/embaralha 
> palavra.py", line 1, in <module>   a,b,c = input('informe 3 numeros:
> ').split("") ValueError: empty separator
> ```

Comment: Você está informando os números separados por espaço, mas está tentando dividir a *string* com `""`, por que? Faça o `.split(" ")` para separar no espaço em branco.

Comment: Pode também fazer `split()` sem indicar o separador que o separador por defeito é um espaço e vai dividir por palavras como pretende.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível, a função [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) só retorna **um** valor sempre. Inclusive o que está tentando fazer não é retornar 3 dados separados, está retornando um valor e o está quebrando em 3 logo depois do `input()` (o `input()` já foi executado e trouxe uma só *string*) com o seu resultado, e aí pode jogar nas variáveis diversas.

O erro é que está tentando quebrar os dados com um separador vazio, isto não dá certo, teria que por um espaço:

```
a, b, c = input('informe 3 numeros: ').split(" ")
print(a, '', b, '', c)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/11KeiK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InputSplitpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/InputSplit.py).

Mas isto só funciona se a pessoa digitar certinho, com os espaços corretos. Portanto não faça assim, faça 3 `input()`s e seja feliz. Mesmo em C é melhor assim.

E note que em C já guarda como inteiro (na forma mostrada), em Python ainda terá um texto, e se quer número teria que fazer a conversão individualmente em cada variável.

Answer (score 2):

ValueError: empty separator

Ao inves de .split(""), faça .split(" ")

So lembrando que o input retorna uma string, ou seja, se quiser usar como operandos tera que transformar para inteiro ou float. E tambem neste tipo de entrada a validação tem que ser feita, pois o usuario pode por 3 espaços entre cada numero, ai vai da merda...

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua intenção for capturar vários valores a partir de um só **input()**, você pode utilizar uma das linhas de comandos listadas abaixo:

**Exemplo 1:**

```
valores = list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores: ).split()))
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
valores = [int(x) for in input('Digite todos os valores: ).split()]
```

**Exemplo 3:**

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for in input('Digite todos os valores: ).split()]
```

Observe que quando executamos cada um dos **3** exemplos listados acima, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores pretendidos, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Em ambos exemplos, os valores capturados pelo **input()** são armazenados em uma lista.

Nos dois primeiros exemplos podemos digitar uma quantidade **indefinida** de valores, ou seja, **quantos** valores quisermos.

No terceiro exemplo, só poderemos digitar a **quantidade** de valores que seja **igual à quantidade de variáveis** que, porventura, esteja do **lado esquerdo** do sinal de atribuição - que no Pytho é representado pelo sinal `=`. Neste caso específico, só poderemos digitar **3** valores.

Além disso, observe que para utilizarmos uma das três formas listadas acima, precisamos identificar o **tipo** de variável desejada. Nos exemplos citados acima, utilizei apenas o tipo inteiro - **int**. Porém, poderemos utilizar outros tipos de variáveis. Para isso, basta substituir o tipo **int**, pelo tipo desejado.

Comment: [Veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/como-atribuir-3-valores-para-3-vari%c3%a1veis-em-apenas-uma-linha-de-entrada-em-pytho)